# python-Implement and test the following BST method

Tags: python, data-structures, binary-search-tree

Implement and test the following BST method

I am working with this code to implement binary tree node class and the binary tree class to check whether two BSTs are identical. The method is recursive and requires an auxiliary function.

This is what I have so far, I am having trouble writing a main program. Can someone please help me.

```
def is_identical(self, rs):

    identical = self._is_identical_aux(self._root, rs._root)
    return identical

def _is_identical_aux(self, node1, node2):

    result = True
    if node1._value != node2._value:
        result = False
    if node1._left is not None and node2._left is not None and result == True:
        result = self._is_identical_aux(node1._left, node2._left)
    if node1.right is not None and node2._right is not None and result == True:
        result = self._is_identical_aux(node1._right, node2._right)
    return result
```

Comment: What do you mean the main program?? You mean constructing the binary tree and calling `is_identical()`? You haven't provided enough details...

Comment: @AChampion  yeah,  Driver program to test the function.

Comment: Do you want us to write a code to test your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks wrong. Please try following code.

```
def _is_identical_aux(self, node1, node2):
    if node1 is None and node2 is None:
        return True
    if node1 is not None and node2 is not None:
        return ((node1._value == node2._value) and
                _is_identical_aux(node1.left, node2.left) and
                _is_identical_aux(node1.right, node2.right))
    return False
```

Here is the test:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self._value = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

def _is_identical_aux(node1, node2):
    if node1 is None and node2 is None:
        return True
    if node1 is not None and node2 is not None:
        return ((node1._value == node2._value) and
                _is_identical_aux(node1.left, node2.left) and
                _is_identical_aux(node1.right, node2.right))
    return False

root1 = Node(7)
root1.left = Node(3)
root1.right = Node(2)
root1.left.left = Node(123)
root1.left.right = Node(231)
root1.right.left = Node(9)
root1.right.right = Node(5)

root2 = Node(7)
root2.left = Node(3)
root2.right = Node(2)
root2.left.left = Node(123)
root2.left.right = Node(231)
root2.right.left = Node(9)
root2.right.right = Node(5)

root3 = Node(7)
root3.left = Node(3)
root3.right = Node(2)

if _is_identical_aux(root1, root2):
    print "Both trees are identical"
else:
    print "Trees are not identical"

if _is_identical_aux(root1, root3):
    print "Both trees are identical"
else:
    print "Trees are not identical"
```

Results:

```
Both trees are identical
Trees are not identical
```

Comment: How can I input two binary trees to test them, this is what I meant and thank you.